# Getting an error when using event bus to communicate data?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have two components that need to share data. This is the first one

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
     <label id="chatRoom">{{chatRoom}} <input type="text" id="chatInput" v-model="chatRoomVal"></label>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {bus} from '../main'
export default{
  name: 'chat-room',
  data: function () {
    return {
      chatRoom: 'Chat Room: ',
      chatRoomVal: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    emitChatRoomVal: function () {
      bus.$emit('chatRoom', this.chatRoomVal)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This is the second one

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <button id="submit" v-on:click="submitForm">{{buttonText}}</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {bus} from '../main'
export default{
  name: 'form-submit',
  data: function () {
    return {
      buttonText: 'Submit'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submitForm: function () {
      bus.$on('chatRoom', (data) => {
        alert(data)
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I am trying to make my second component use the chatRoomVal variable using event bus. However, the alert() method is not working so I assume the code breaks at bus.$on. Why is my code not working?

Answer (score 0):

Use global singleton.

Better understand **[vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/)**

```js
Vue.component('form-input', {
  template: '#form-input',
  props: ['model', 'config']
})

Vue.component('form-submit', {
  template: '#form-submit',
  props: ['model', 'config'],
  methods: {
    submitForm: function () {
      console.log(this.model)
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    model: {},
    config:{
      input1:{
        text: 'input1',
        id: 'input1'
      },
      input2:{
        text: 'input2',
        id: 'input2'
      },
      button: {
        text: 'Submit'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <form-input :model="model" :config="config.input1"></form-input>
  <form-input :model="model" :config="config.input2"></form-input>
  <form-submit :model="model" :config="config.button"></form-submit>
</div>

<template id="form-input">
  <div class="row">
    <label>{{config.text}} <input type="text" v-model="model[config.id]"></label>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="form-submit">
  <div class="row">
    <button @click="submitForm">{{config.text}}</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to misunderstand the way an event bus works. When you call `on`, you're saying "wait for someone to emit this event". I don't see that there's any reason to expect that `emitChatRoomVal` will have been called at some time shortly after `submitForm`.

Since the data item is supposed to be shared, you might make it owned by the bus itself. Or you might define an event that requests the value of `chatRoomVal`, so that you can emit the request in your 2nd component, and the 1st component will fire `emitChatRoomVal` in response.